# Being notified when the application menu item of an NSApplication's mainMenu is being highlighted

Tags: swift, macos

I've got a status bar app. The user can check an option such that the status bar is not used ; in that case, the app will launch 'normally', having a dock icon and a typical main menu.

Thing is, I need to know when the application menu is being highlighted. The application menu is that item in the application's main menu that has the application's name as its title.

I've tried to assign a target and action as well as a delegate, but neither the action or the delegate methods are being called. There's no documentation about this anywhere. Any idea what's happening?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code and/or what you've already tried to do?

Comment: Don't send us links to ZIPs! Edit your post and include some code there.

Comment: It's the same code as the answer below, starting from a template. I literally did what he said. I can hardly give code of my own app since it's intermingled with lots of unrelated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's no documentation about this anywhere

There is one: [NSMenuDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsmenudelegate)

- Extend AppDelegate to conform to `NSMenuDelegate` and implement `menuWillOpen`, replace `<name of application>` with the application name

  ```
  extension AppDelegate : NSMenuDelegate {
      func menuWillOpen(_ menu: NSMenu) {
          if menu.title == "<name of application>" {
              print("application menu will open")
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- In Interface Builder connect the `delegate` property of the application menu to AppDelegate

Comment: Have you made that work in an app? Won't work at my end, even when I start from an XCode template.

Comment: Yes, of course. You have to ensure that the delegate of the **menu** is connected rather than any **menu item**

Comment: Can't connect a menu item, but I did connect the wrong menu (main menu instead of the application menu). Thanks!